# Synchronization MATERIALIZED VIEW between databases on different servers (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

Right now I have the instance of Postgres 14 where for some data I create MATERIALIZED VIEW. I have something around 20. Now I want to share that data with other teams. My first thought was queue. But I do not know if it is not an overkill as long as I have to sync data once per 20-24h. My second thought was to use replication, but as I see it does not support materialized view.

My question is if I have more option and which one will be the best for me?